# How can I use couchDB in my java project?

Tags: web, couchdb

I'm new to couchDB.
I want to use couchDB to manage document in my project.
I've test run the demo in couchDB at

> CouchDB\share\couchdb\www

But I don't know how can I use couchDB in my java project?
In addition，my project is a j2ee web project and I run it in tomcat.

Comment: I'm no JAVA dev but the beauty of CouchDb is that you communicate with it using plain old HttpRequests and HttpResponses and it's API is REST oriented. So you would either just start with doing this manually and reading the docs (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/) about the params for each request etc.

Comment: What exactly do you want to combine? How would you "combine" your project with a different type of database?

Comment: So sorry for my poor English. I just want to say how them coummunicate with each other.Could you give me a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel says, once you have CouchDB up and running you communicate with it over HTTP. You can use the standard Java HTTP libraries, or any other of your choice.

There are several client libraries available which offer varying levels of abstraction over the raw HTTP interface. There are several listed here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java. [Ektorp](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp) provides a high level object-based abstraction and [Lightcouch](http://www.lightcouch.org/) gives you one much closer to the HTTP layer.